# Gradient distribution of element in array

Tags: java, javascript, php, actionscript-3

this may be a dumb question,so sorry in advance.

I need to distribute 2 kinds of elements in an array, like in a gradient (is the image that comes to mind).

I'll try to explain (sorry again, I don't know some terms).

I have an array of X,Y objects, I'd like to arrange them like this (array.length will be fixed)

[X,X,X,Y,X,Y,X,Y,Y,Y] - in the middle, when X is disappearing , y start to show, and I'm always sure that array[0] is always X , and array[array.lenght-1] is always Y.

How to do this ?

Sorry again if the question isn't so clear.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? I get the feeling this might be an [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: You are looking at some form of dithering algorithm. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither I think I've found a way, in a few hours I'll upload a prototype.

Comment: i don't know what to try, or better, if my tries are correct: i tried to weight each position, a double linear interpolation, i looked at also at algorithms to make gradients in PHP .... but it seems i'm in a bottle neck ). (as is said, i also don't know where to look at!) @Pier thanks, i'll thinks this could be a solution, have to read well the article you linked! (srry guys i can't add an '@' for each of you in the comment)

Comment: @John V. I need this to disribuite building alon a  track: Going to Y from X, where X is a dark city and Y a eco friendly city, i want to blend side building from an X-graphics to Y-graphics, in a 'natural' way. This track is randomly generated, so i can't place buildings 'by hands'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't perfect (not even slightly), but it *might* meed your needs, at the very least it might give you some inspiration:

```
<?php
$Class1 = 'a';
$Class2 = 'b';

print_r(gradient($Class1, $Class2, 10));

function gradient($class1, $class2, $size){
    $result = array();

    for($i=0; $i<$size; $i++){
        $result[$i] = rand(0, 99) >= $i/$size*100 ? $class1 : $class2;
    }

    return $result;
}
?>
```

Sample output (higher sizes will make it closer to your example):

```
Array ( [0] => a [1] => a [2] => a [3] => a [4] => b [5] => b [6] => a [7] => b [8] => b [9] => a )
```

Comment: I accepted this because it point me to the right direction, even if it isnt really the correct function to achieve my goal. Howver, many thanks!

Comment: @DavideArcinotti Feel free to update the question or post your answer as an answer, I'm curious to know what you went with.